# Trigger a Link once a new post is Published

Tags: wordpress

Is there Anyway to trigger a link once new post is Publish ?. My goal is to use it to ping sitemap

```
http://google.com/ping?sitemap=http://www.example.com/my_sitemap.xml
```

I simply don't want to set cron job for this. Please Gurus in the house is there anyway I can use theme function to achieve this ? I am new to wp coding Please.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wordpress Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post):

> `publish_post` is an action triggered whenever a post is updated and its new status is "publish"

So in your theme's `functions.php`, write your function to call the google url, then use the `add_action` function, with `publish_post` as the hook, and your function's name as the callback.

Comment: I am new to wp coding. Is there any way you can help out ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function test()
{
  write code here.....
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'test' );
```

Comment: While a nicely formatted block of text is very helpful it is best practices to include a little explanation of the code.